# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined javascript error

Tags: javascript, json, browserify

This question is very common one, however none of the solution had worked for me.
I am trying to use "require" to file system module but I keep runnig to this error.
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

I realize that I need to use browserify to get "require" to work on client side so I installed it but no luck.

Comment: Can you share some more info about where and how you are running this code?

Comment: I am using vscode to write the code with js and html file and I am testing it through the browser. I tried to create new project just to test the function and I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: do you have node installed on your system @Mahmood ?

Comment: @Nishant Yes I do

Comment: How are you using `browserify`? Could you share the steps leading up to the error?

Comment: check node version by node -v.

**const fs = require('fs');
console.log(fs);**

ran the code by node <name>.js, it showed up the details

Comment: @Nishant Thanks for your time, I am completely new to JavaScript, I figured that I didn't use Browserify correctly (I missed the most important step whrere I have to compile my code with browserify).

Comment: @JonathanWieben Thanks for your time, your comment made me re-check my steps, I just missed a step where I have to compile my code with browserify.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your replies I figured that I didn't understand how to use Browserify. I just had to compile my code with Browserify `browserify main.js -o bundle.js`, then link it to my html `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` (I am new to this obviously and my mind is blown now LOL).